# cURL/GuzzleHTTP check status code of direct download link

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

i have direct download link from google drive like this

```
https://doc-08-48-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/xxxx?e=download
```

from the given download link i want to check if the given link is still valid or not, how i can achieve it using `cURL` or `GuzzleHTTP`?

Answer (score 0):

i found out solution, here's what i use to validate direct download link

```
$url = "https://doc-08-48-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/xxxxxx?e=download";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_exec( $ch );
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);echo $statusCode;
```

hope it help the others, cheers!